# Slice an array with a list of indices

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, slice

Suppose `a = array([1,2,3])` and `b = array([4,5,6])`. I want to slice `a` and `b` using a list and perform some operation on each part, then return the result to an array. For example i propose a dummy function that demonstrates the usage:

```
def dummy_function(i):
  A = sum(a[:i])
  B = sum(cumsum(b[i:]))
  return A*B
```

For example, this function would return `dummy_function(2) = 18`, and `dummy_function(1) = 16` but I would like to evaluate it using a list as its argument:

```
>>> dummy_function([2,1])
array([18,16])
```

Instead I get `IndexError: invalid slice`. I don't want to use a loop to iterate over the elements of `[2,1]` because I believe it can be done more effectively. How can I do what I want?

Comment: You could use `numpy.vectorize`

Comment: Is `func` the actual function in your use-case or just a dummy one to showcase your usage?

Comment: Do you mean to get 18 for `func(2)`?

Comment: Yes my thinking was func(2) = 18 because A = 1+2 = 3 and B = 6, so func(2) = A*B = 3*6=18

Comment: func is just a dummy function

Comment: How did you get 18 from `dummy_function(2)`? If `i` = 2, `b[i+1:]` will be an empty array!

Comment: Also what does "relatively fast" mean here? If you want to slice multiple times then you have to slice multiple times.. There is no way around that unless there is some pattern in the slice indices that you could perhaps exploit to reduce the number of computations.

Comment: @John relatively fast is not a fixed number. I just want my program to scale as well as possible

Comment: Did you do any profiling? Unless you are certain slicing multiple times is the bottleneck, you may very well be trying to micro-optimize.

Comment: No, I don't know how to do that unless I have some other implementation to relate it to

Comment: `b[0:]` and `b[1:]` are two different size arrays.  So you can't produce both with one indexing step.

Comment: If the slices are always used in a `sum` you might be able to do clever stuff with `cumsum`, e.g. `np.cumsum(b)[2,4]` instead of `[sum(b[:2]), sum(b[:4])]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you want correctly, but this worked for me:

```
import numpy as np  


def func(i):
  a = np.array([1,2,3])
  b = np.array([4,5,6])
  A = np.sum(a[:i])
  B = np.cumsum(b[i:])
  C = A*B
  return C[0]

print(func(2))
```

The result is 18
If you want to give your 'func' a list as argument, then you probably should loop over the list elements..

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't express myself clearly enough then. My function already does this. What I am asking is how to write code such that I can give the function a list and return an array. Thanks for pointing out an error in my code

Comment: Why you just don't use a for loop?

Comment: The problem with the present implementation (using a for-loop) is that it is running unacceptably slow